# How to pass Value inserted in text box of Active choice reactive parameter to job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I'm in "build with parameters" before starting job, I want to pass the value entered in a textbox to the Job. I´m using Active choice and  Active choice reactive parameter like this:

[image: Parameters]

This is the groovy script which I then use to run job and show output. But I´m getting NULL on `echo` command.

```
node {       
    def commit = params.val

    stage ('Pulling code from Bitbucket') {

        git branch: 'master',
            credentialsId: '2bbc73c4-254e-45bd-85f4-6a169699310c',
            url: 'git@bitbucket.org:repo/test.git'


        sh (""" echo ${commit}""")  
    }
}
```

Which is the correct way to pass parameter into build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output, you have defined a parameter named `ID1` that references some other parameter named `OPTIONS`. The correct way to reference these parameters is `params.ID1` and `params.OPTIONS`. I can't see a parameter named `val` that can be addressed by `params.val`.